# Dual-boot => Unsupported partition table

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot

I have a Dell Inspiron 5521 with dual boot (Legacy Boot, UEFI off):
- Ubuntu 12.04.2
- Windows 7

First I've installed Ubuntu and after Windows 7. The problem is that when I'm trying to activate windows using Windows Loader I'm getting a weird message: Unsupported Partition Table. The only answer I've found to this problem is to reformat the entire hdd but this isn't a solution. Can someone suggest a better idea ?

Regards.

Comment: always install Windows first and next other Operating Systems.

Comment: Paste the output of `gdisk -l /dev/<path_to_your_disk>`.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you have GPT(GUID Partition Table), But Windows 7 works at MBR-type table only, so if you check it from Linux(install GParted) and it is a problem go to >> [this Link](http://www.firewing1.com/node/610)

Comment: Windows 7 supports GPT and MBR...

Comment: Windows 7 supports reading both GPT and MBR disk, but will only boot on MBR disk in BIOS mode, and on GPT disk in UEFI mode.